# There are at most $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ $r$-element subsets of $[n]$ with pairwise non-empty intersection

Tags: combinatorics

Let $2 < r< \frac n2$.

Let $\mathcal F$ be  a family of sets consisting of $r$ elements subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

If the intersection of any $2$ elements of $\mathcal F$ is not an empty set then show that the number of elements $$\text{card}(\mathcal F) \le \binom{n-1}{r-1}.$$

Comment: ...and what does that "Z (integer modulo)..." thing has to do with the question?

Comment: @DonAntonio I can't parse any of this...

Comment: it is a set containing numbers 1 to n

Comment: here 1 to n are the remainders that we can get after dividing a number by n

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Then why not take simply **the set** $\;\{1,2,3,...,n\}\;$ ??

Comment: yes u can take that only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Erdős–Ko–Rado theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem)

Note that the upper bound is easily attained by all $r$-element sets that contain the element $1$.